# R fast cosine distance between consecutive rows of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How can I efficiently calculate distances between (almost) consecutive rows of a large-ish (~4m rows) of a data.table? I've outlined my current approach, but it is very slow. My actual data has up to a few hundred columns. I need to calculate lags and leads for future use, so I create these and use them to calculate distances.

```
library(data.table)
library(proxy)

set_shift_col <- function(df, shift_dir, shift_num, data_cols, byvars = NULL){
  df[, (paste0(data_cols, "_", shift_dir, shift_num)) := shift(.SD, shift_num, fill = NA, type = shift_dir), byvars, .SDcols = data_cols]
}

set_shift_dist <- function(dt, shift_dir, shift_num, data_cols){
  stopifnot(shift_dir %in% c("lag", "lead"))
  shift_str <- paste0(shift_dir, shift_num)
  dt[, (paste0("dist", "_", shift_str)) := as.numeric(
    proxy::dist(
      rbindlist(list(
        .SD[,data_cols, with=FALSE], 
        .SD[, paste0(data_cols, "_" , shift_str), with=FALSE]
      ), use.names = FALSE), 
      method = "cosine")
  ), 1:nrow(dt)]
}

n <- 10000
test_data <- data.table(a = rnorm(n), b = rnorm(n), c = rnorm(n), d = rnorm(n))

cols <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

set_shift_col(test_data, "lag", 1, cols)
set_shift_col(test_data, "lag", 2, cols)
set_shift_col(test_data, "lead", 1, cols)
set_shift_col(test_data, "lead", 2, cols)

set_shift_dist(test_data, "lag", 1, cols)
```

I'm sure this is a very inefficient approach, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the vectorisation efficiencies in the `proxy::dist` function - rather than call it once for each row you can get all the distances you need from a single call.

Try this replacement function and compare the speed:

```
set_shift_dist2 <- function(dt, shift_dir, shift_num, data_cols){
  stopifnot(shift_dir %in% c("lag", "lead"))
  shift_str <- paste0(shift_dir, shift_num)
  dt[, (paste0("dist2", "_", shift_str)) := proxy::dist(
    .SD[,data_cols, with=FALSE], 
    .SD[, paste0(data_cols, "_" , shift_str), with=FALSE], 
    method = "cosine", 
    pairwise = TRUE
  )]
}
```

You could also do it in one go without storing copies of the data in the table

```
test_data[, dist_lag1 := proxy::dist(
  .SD, 
  as.data.table(shift(.SD, 1)), 
  pairwise = TRUE, 
  method = 'cosine'
  ), .SDcols = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```